# How to increase UITextView font size when UITextView's size increases

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uifont

I am developing an app which has a feature adding `TextView` dynamically, increasing and decreasing its size when we are dragging it.

I can adjust the text view size according to the number of characters by setting `TextView`'s content size to `TextView`'s size.

When dragging the `TextView` corners, I increase the size of `TextView`. I can do this successfully.

When I am dragging `TextView`'s corners, its size is increasing, but font size is not increasing. Is there any way to increase or decrease `TextView` font size automatically when `TextView` size increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code hope it helps.i found from [the Link.](http://derekneely.com/2011/04/size-to-fit-text-in-uitextview-iphone/)

```
#define kDefaultFontSize 24.0


if (myTextView.contentSize.height > myTextView.frame.size.height) {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (myTextView.contentSize.height > myTextView.frame.size.height) {
        myTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kDefaultFontSize-fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}
```